# crash when using windows platform 5.3.8 PHP 's function DOTNET()

Tags: c#, php, .net, iis, fastcgi

I am running PHP 5.3.8 non-thread-safe version with IIS 7 on windows server 2008 . I have the following code

```
<?php
echo "Started..<br/>";

$outStr = "";
 $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
 $stack->Push(".Net");
 $stack->Push("Hello ");
 echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
 echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']."<br/>";
?>
```

It will crash every other time ( work , crash , work , crash, .... etc ).
The error reported to the web browser is :

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
c:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

I tried other .net assemblies (I wrote with C#) and get the same crashing behaviour (every other time).

Please help.

I am using .net 4 . In my c:\php directory I have  a php-cgi.exe.config file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

But even with .net 3.5 I get the same crashing behaviour.

If I run the php script in command line as follow , it seems to work everytimes, but I really need my php web app to work without crashes ( I have NO php.exe.config .. none )

```
\php\php.exe  testscript.php
```

Comment: Could you describe what you're using .NET to do? The example you give is replaceable with `\SplStack`.

Comment: OTOH, you're already writing some part of this in C# and running in IIS/Windows. Is this a migration from ASP.NET to PHP, or the other way around?

Comment: I am using an existing C# project , which has a library that is useful for an existing php site. I am trying to integrate them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour appears to be a known bug:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53140&edit=1

Comment: mmmm, yes, in fact, the code of OP is copied from the bug report